# how to handel % in post method in php

Tags: php, mysql, api, post

Im send a mysql query in php variable using post method having % value;

```
 $Brand= 'SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE STATUS='1' AND UNIT_CODE like '%"81"%'';

$Brand=$_POST['Brand'];

echo $Brand;
```

and result is

```
    SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE STATUS='1' AND UNIT_CODE like '%
```

How can I get the complete string using this

Comment: The solution here is parameterised queries...which you should be using anyway.

Comment: Please share more details - how **exactly** do you build that SQL query?

Comment: P.S. the code you've shown doesn't actually make any sense as an example. It's not valid syntax, it overwrites $Brand and it doesn't show how you actually try to include the real user input.

Comment: writing in variable as shown

Comment: Which mysql database library are you using? Mysqli? PDO? Something else? They all support parameterised queries. The value you pass in should be done via a parameter, in all cases. It's not really any different for a LIKE wildcard than for anything else. Tutorials can show you. If you tell us the database library we can probably point you to a previous question on this site about this exact topic.

Comment: It seems like you're having an issue with mixing single/double quotes. You can see that the syntax highlighter is having a hard time (and your result isnt what you want). I suggest you read up a little into that (not difficult stuff) and then build your query step for step :)

Comment: P.S. If you're just hardcoding 81 every time (although that doesn't seem realistic), then you don't need parameters and it's simply done like this: `$Brand= "SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE STATUS='1' AND UNIT_CODE like '%81%'";`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Brand= "SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE STATUS='1' AND UNIT_CODE like '%81%'";
$Brand=$_POST['Brand'];

echo $Brand;
```

And the result will be like:

```
SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE STATUS='1' AND UNIT_CODE like '%81%'
```

Comment: `And the result will be like`...actually it won't, the result will be whatever the content of `$_POST["brand"]` is. The SQL will be overwritten. The OP's code makes no sense in that respect...probably best not to copy it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a prepared statement any time variables are involved and especially when they come from $_GET/$_POST requests to avoid MySQL injection.

Although your request isn't super-clear I'm taking a stab in the dark and assuming that you're trying to at least run a different or modified version of that query based on some sort of user interaction - while I haven't tested the below code it should serve as a good starting point for how you can modify queries safely using prepared statements and PDO.

You can view the following link for reference https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

```
<?php
// Configure the below based on your DB
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

// Leave this as-is
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

// Attempt connection here accessed via $pdo below
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

// Get your brand variable from post request
$brand = "%{$_POST['Brand']}%";

// Prepare an SQL statement with your status and brand variables
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT BRAND_CODE FROM product WHERE status = ? AND UNIT_CODE LIKE ?");

// Execute the above statement, bind variables here to avoid MySQL injection
$stmt->execute([ 1, $brand ]);

// Retrieve your results (if any)
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Clean up, checks and do what you will with the results..
```

Comment: The only thing I'd take issue with here, as a generic example, is the use of "root" as the database login. It's very bad practice for a web app (even a test version) to login as root. It should never appear in an example, as people often have a tendency to take literally / copy verbatim the parts they either don't fully understand or aren't as interested in. If you're going to demonstrate best practice it would be good if the whole example demonstrates it, in all aspects. :-)

Comment: Actually. I'm also not sure about `catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}`. What's the point of that exactly? It seems to just catch and re-throw the exact same exception. If you're catching exceptions, then log them and output a clean error message or something. If you're just going to re-throw, then save some CPU and let the exception bubble up itself.